# I want to display texts task bar at windows7

Tags: taskbar

Is it possible to display text in the TaskBar as [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmIzV.png).

I'm willing to try any language but just need pointing in the right direction so that I can get a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179(v=vs.85).aspx#tbnotify_Add_Modify_Delete_Icons) might help you.

I'd recommend using C# with the Windows API.

Good luck! It's probably not worth the effort though.